# iOS Adhoc Build で "Code Signing: No matching code signing identity found" エラーが発生する

Tags: ios, monaca

私はドキュメントの手順通り、iOSビルドを実行しました。
Debug Build で実行したら問題無しですが、Adhoc buildでエラーが発生しました。
もちろん、配布用の手順とおりに行いました。
エラー状況は添付しました。
ビルド設定に何を足りないのか気になっています。
他の方はこの状況をあったことがありませんか。
また、対策があれば教えてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: monacaの利用経験はありませんが、"No matching code signing identity found" というエラーから、プロビジョニングプロファイル・証明書・鍵に問題があると察します。

Ad-hoc プロファイルと、同プロファイルで使用する証明書と鍵は、ビルドマシンにインストールされていますか？

Comment: 私は最初からDistribution Certificationの新作成をやり直しましたが問題を解決しなかった。

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージに「Check App ID ~」があるので、アップルのAppIDとMonacaで設定するAppIDが一致していることを確認してみてください。

また、AppleのAppID設定にてワイルドカードを使用している場合は、一致していることの確認ではなく、「com.example.*」を設定した場合は、Monacaの設定で「com.example.xxxx」(「xxxx」は任意文字)となっていることを確認してください。

> > #### 【Apple AppID設定画面】
> >
> > [image: 1 Apple AppID設定画面]
> >
> > #### 【Monaca AppID設定画面】
> >
> > [image: 2 Monaca AppID設定画面]

Comment: コメントを有難うございます。
何度確認しましたが問題がまだ残っています。

皆さんはMonacaでAdhocビルドが順調ですか

Answer (score 0):

みなさんのコメントを有難うございました。

原因がわかりました。
同じ問題ので、このリンクを参考してください。
[Monacaで　iOSアプリのAdhocとReleaseビルドが出来ません](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/8086/monaca%E3%81%A7-ios%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%81%AEadhoc%E3%81%A8release%E3%83%93%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89%E3%81%8C%E5%87%BA%E6%9D%A5%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93)