# Monacaで　iOSアプリのAdhocとReleaseビルドが出来ません

Tags: ios, monaca

iOS アプリは DEBUG ビルドが成功しましたが、
Adhoc と Release ビルドが失敗しました。
エラー Log を見ると

> 1 key imported. Unable to delete certificate matching "iPhone Distribution: XXXXXX Co., Ltd.\C2\A0
>   (XXXXXXXX)" .... Check dependencies Code Sign error: No matching
>   codesigning identity found: No codesigning identities (i.e.
>   certificate and private key pairs) matching 窶彿Phone Distribution:
>   XXXXXX Co., Ltd.\C2\A0 (XXXXXXXX)窶� were found. CodeSign error: code
>   signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK
>   'iOS 8.0'

がありました。

同じ Distribution Cerfiticate と Adhoc Provisioning で XCode6 でビルドが出来ました。
Monaca で対応方法がわかりません。
皆さんはその問題にあったことがありますか。
昔の Cerfiticate を Clean する必要があるがどうやってするかわかりません。

Answer (score 2):

問題を解決しました。
原因はAppleアカウントを登録した時、会社名は一番最後に＜SPACE＞文字が入りました。
「XXXXXX Co., Ltd.＜SPACE＞」になってしまった。
Logファイルを見ると「\C2\A0」文字がありました。

Apple Support Centerに＜SPACE＞を削除してお願いしてから、もう一度Certificateを作成して、ビルドを通常に成功しました。

Middleさんへ、有難うございました。

Answer (score 1):

自分もその問題に当たったことがありますが、自分の場合はプロビジョニングプロファイルとアップロードした証明書に食い違いがありました。正しいプロビジョニングプロファイルをアップロードしたら、正常にビルドすることができました。うまくいかない場合で、公開しているアプリが一つも無い場合は、もう一度最初から設定してみてはどうでしょうか。